# Is line break possible for the data on the same column?

Tags: php, html, select, mysqli, mariadb

I have this table for `project` and `item` which I joined together thru `SQL SELECT STATEMENT` using `INNER JOIN CLAUSE`. Here's what it looks like:

`project`

| ID | Project Name | 
| 1   | CCPP            |

`Items Table`

| ID | Project_ID | Item Name                          | 
| 1    |         1       | Trees Planted                      | 
                          |  Areas Included                    | 
                          | No. of Materials/Equipment |

As you can see, there are more than one data under one column. At some point, I was successful in saving those data with new line `\n` included. However, when I begin sorting it thru SQL SELECT STATEMENT `inner join`. The result displayed this:

|          List of Project                                                                 |
|              CCPP                                                                         |
|  Trees Planted Areas Included No. of Materials /Equipment   |

Here's my code: 
`SELECT project.project_name, item.itemname FROM project project INNER JOIN item item ON project.Project_ID=item.Project_ID`

I tried inserting another `\n` and even `<br>` code after I call the item name but it didn't work out. 
Next, is when I tried to display it using `mysqli_fetch_array` and populate it at a table and putting either a `\t\r\n` to it. But neither of it seems to work.

Here's how I manage to display it: 
`<td><?php echo $row[itemname]."\n"; ?></td>` 
But it didn't give me the desired output.

I want it to be like this... 
| List of Project      |
|Trees Planted       |
|Areas Included     |
|Equipment           |

Anyone who knows how can I put a line break between those data under one `db column`?

Do you have any *working* suggestions?

Comment: Does `nl2br()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) do the job?

Comment: Uhm, it does work... if I only want the text to have a line break. But, since I'm using an editable table (where the editable grid/columns relies solely on the number of those data), I can't get the desire output...

Comment: It worked! For some reason its now working. :)
To end this question, I might gonna vote for your answer @NigelRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `nl2br()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) should do the job.

```
<td><?php echo nl2br($row[itemname]); ?></td>
```